# Flyway - why all my schemas were deleted and how can i revert it

Tags: database-schema, flyway, dbmigrate, repair

I was running a `db repair` command on my db, and surpassingly found out later that for each old migration version a new `DELETE` migration was created.
It was only effecting the `flyway_schema_history` table, the rest of the tables stayed the same, and nothing was deleted/ dropped.

But, now when I am trying to run migrations scripts I get failures when running the flyway, since it tries to run the first migration script again. I do not want to delete this migrations.

Can someone explain to me why did it happen, and much more important, do I have a way to revert it and delete the `DELETE` rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Flyway 7, running [`repair`](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/repair-184127461.html) marks any migrations that are `Missing` as `DELETED` in the `flyway_schema_history` table, which is a way of telling Flyway that the migrations have been removed

If the migrations aren't `Missing`, what has likely happened is you haven't configured [`flyway.locations`](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/locations-184127514.html) when running `repair`

As for fixing it, there are two options that are the most ideal as of today:

- If you have Flyway Teams or Enterprise edition, or are able to get a trial, you can use [`flyway.skipExecutingMigrations`](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/skip-executing-migrations-184127537.html) when running `migrate` to update the `flyway_schema_history` table, telling Flyway that the migrations are applied again, without actually executing them
- Otherwise, you could go directly into the `flyway_schema_history` table and delete the `DELETE` rows

Comment: Since it was urgent, and I saw no harm in it, I already done 2, though I found it a bad practice.

Comment: In order to avoide doing it again in the next time, can you please explain a bit or give a link to an explanation about what is the locations and how is it specified?

Comment: `flyway.locations` is documented [here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/locations-184127514.html) and includes what it's for and how to specify it. To summarise, it's the locations where your migrations are, and `repair` needs to know, otherwise it treats migrations that have already been applied as `Missing` if it can't find them in any of the configured locations. I've updated the answer with a link to the docs for `locations` too